# Are there any reasons why the StringPiece/StringRef idiom is not more popular?

Tags: c++, string

From the documentation of the [StringPiece class in Chromium's source code](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/string_piece.h?view=markup):

```
// A string-like object that points to a sized piece of memory.
//
// Functions or methods may use const StringPiece& parameters to accept either
// a "const char*" or a "string" value that will be implicitly converted to
// a StringPiece.  
//
// Systematic usage of StringPiece is encouraged as it will reduce unnecessary
// conversions from "const char*" to "string" and back again.
```

Example of use:

```
void foo(StringPiece const & str) // Pass by ref. is probably not needed
{
   // str has same interface of const std::string
}

int main()
{
    string bar("bar");
    foo(bar); // OK, no mem. alloc.

    // No mem. alloc. either, would be if arg. of "foo" was std::string
    foo("baz");  
}
```

This seems like such an important and obvious optimization that I can't understand why it's not more widespread, and why a class similar to StringPiece is not already in the standard.

Are there any reasons why I shouldn't replace the use of `string` and `char*` parameters in my own code with this class? Is there anything like it already in the C++ standard libraries?

**UPDATE**. I've learnt that LLVM's source uses a similar concept: the [StringRef](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#StringRef) class.

Comment: I like this as a theoretical idea. I wonder how confusing it would be in practice without "training".

Comment: Old post, but for future readers should note it has been proposed: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3442.html

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Because why bother? With copy elision and/or pass by reference, memory allocations for `std::string` can usually be avoided as well.

The string situation in C++ is confusing enough as it is, without adding still more string classes.

If the language was to be redesigned from scratch, or if backwards compatibility wasn't an issue, then this is one of many possible improvements that could be done to string handling in C++. But now that we're stuck with both `char*` and `std::string`, adding a stringref-style class into the mix would cause a lot of confusion, with limited benefit.

Apart from this, isn't the same effect achieved more idiomatically with a pair of iterators?
If I want to pass a sequence of characters, whether they belong to a string or a `char*`, why shouldn't I just use a pair of iterators to delimit them?

Comment: But if you go the "two iterators" route, then you have to invent a class analogous to StringPiece that gives you a convenient string-like interface. And the first line of your functions would always be something like "StringRange str(str_beg, str_end);". Accepted anyway for providing the best assessment so far.

Comment: True about the convenient string-like interface, but again, remember that iterators are already idiomatic in C++. I don't see why your functions would need to create a stringrange from the iterators. Instead, the entire string manipulation interface should have been provided as free functions on iterators to begin with. Boost's StringAlgo library fixes much of this.

Comment: I don't think you would really like what you are suggesting. Imagine something as simple as `strA+strB+strC` in terms of iterators.

Comment: I never said it was an ideal solution. ;) But then a better solution would be to add a *general* Range object, which could be used not just for strings, but for any type of ranges.

Comment: See Boost.Range lib. and its future replacement, Boost.RangeEx. I dream one day they'll be in the standard.

Comment: The reason to bother is because we are stuck with std::string and const char* and it is handy for leaf-functions to be able to handle both in a single function. Using StringPiece is simpler and clearer than using a pair of iterators.

Answer (score 12):

Bit later, but ...

Idea behind StringPiece is very good. The class can capture both `std::string` and `const char *` and pass them to a function. Here is an example:

```
void process(const StringRef s){
   // do something
}

process("Hello"); // const char *
std::string s = "Hello";
process(s); // std::string
process(std::string("Hello")); // std::string rvalue
```

If function accepted `std::string` you actually creating a temporary object if you pass `const char *` and whole char is copied (for example with `memcpy`).

You also does not need to worry about livetime, because you are passing `StringRef` to function / method.

There are such class in:

- Google - StringPiece
- boost - boost::string_ref
- LLVM - StringRef

My own (incomplete) implementation can be seen here:
https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM3/blob/master/include/stringref.h

Update 2016:

In C++17, there are `std::string_view`. I did not study it in details, but in general it has same idea. Also similar to mine implementation it have `constexpr` c-tor, so you can create objects at compile time and use it along with other `constexpr` functions.

Answer (score 4):

The question has been very well answered already, but to give some more context, the `StringPiece` pattern is very widely used internally at Google and has been for many years. It is strongly recommended in Google coding guidelines, which is almost surely why Chrome (and subsequently Chromium) have adopted it.

Answer (score 2):

`StringPiece` keeps a pointer to the string data that is passed to its constructor. Thus it relies on the lifetime of that string to be longer than the StringPiece. This is guaranteed if you are using StringPiece as a function parameter; not so if you're keeping a copy of the string in a class member for example.

It's not quite as universal as std::string, and it's definitely not a replacement for it.

Comment: Yes, you should never keep a copy of it. I think this can be trivially enforced by making its copy ctor. and op= private. As for not being an universal replacement for std::string, I agree. Both are intended to work together. std::string => generic use; StringPiece => only as a read-only function parameter

Comment: I would disallow assignment only because I would require that all methods on the class be declared const, reinforcing that this is a const object. I suppose the practice of declaring copy ctor and assignment in pairs is the only reason not to allow a copy ctor.

Comment: @jmucchiello - And also to prevent people from storing their own copy of the string and keeping it alive longer that the function. I don't think you can prevent that unless you disable the copy ctor.

Answer (score 0):

The standard is trying to move away from const char* in favor of string altogether, so adding more options for conversion is useless.

Also note that a nice formed program should use either string or const char* all around ;).

Comment: @Kornel Kisielewicz: But how is it useless if it saves a memory allocation, which can be expensive if the string is long? I thought C++ was about "don't pay for what you don't use".

Comment: @Manuel - it violates the DRY principle, and has all the pitfall that come from that

Comment: Moving away from const char* is never going to happen.  String constants are still appropriate in some contexts, and copying them to a string object is wasteful. Also, while it is trivial to have const char* constants as global objects doing the same thing with std::string is somewhere between tricky and impossible.

Answer (score 0):

StringPiece is great but the pieces aren't null terminated.  If you need to pass to lower level interfaces that take null terminated strings, you need to copy the stringpiece into a null terminated string.

(Not everyone has bought into STL or std::string.)