# Optimization in std::string based on same const literals

Tags: c++

We know compilers can reuse identical constant string literal to save memory efficiently. This optimization is optional for compilers.

*[Two string literals have the same pointer value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13515561/952747)*

```
const char *s1 = "HELLO";
const char *s2 = "HELLO";
```

`s1` and `s2` can have same address. They have the same address in many compilers. For example, both are pointing to the address `0x409044`.

Well.

The question in my mind is, why `std::string` dosen't try to has same advantage? And it doesn't try to just wrap `std::string` around that address.

```
const std::string ss1("HELLO");
const std::string ss2("HELLO");

cout << (void*) ss1.c_str() << endl;
cout << (void*) ss2.c_str() << endl;
```

`ss1` and `ss2` have two distinct addresses.

Is it technically impossible? Prohibited by the language? Or the developers of implementations of the standard library just don't want it?

Comment: I *think* this is forbidden by the C++11 Standard, because such copy-on-write implementations of `std::string` would cause problems in a multithreaded environment

Comment: @AndyProwl: Seems logical, would you please show the paragraph if it's possible?

Comment: See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11)

Comment: @Andy can you give a paragraph number in the standard?

Comment: i had a similar question some time ago - and got a lot of interesting discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312860/correct-idiom-for-stdstring-constants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard library classes by and large all implement strong value semantics, which means that each object owns all its data, and so the lifetime of the object is easy to reason about. While a reference-tracking implementation *might* be possible, it would come at a considerable complexity cost, and that doesn't fit the "don't pay for what you didn't ask for" philosophy of C++.

There have long been discussions about non-owning string-like classes (something like `string_ref` and `array_ref`, if you want to search for it), which would only be *views* on existing strings. This would put the burden on the user to ensure that the lifetime of the underlying shared data fits the application. It might become part of the standard in the future, but search around for existing implementations if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this behaviour might be the memory management of the objects:

The `std::string` objects are responsible for their character arrays. That implies that the arrays are deleted in the `std::string` destructor - and such an array should only be deleted once.

In C char arrays declared as

```
const char* bla = "blabla";
```

are - or should never be - freed.