# How to assign a string literal

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++14

I'm a Java Programmer; I last wrote C or C++ 20 years ago. Now I've returned, I'm trying to use a more modern C++ such as C++11/C++14 and to avoid old c-style programming.

How do I assign a string, as in Java:

```java
private static final String MY_STRING = "Hello World"; // could also be public
```

Now I have the reference `MY_STRING` to the text `"Hello World"`, which I can use as many times in my program as I want, and if I wish to change it to say `"Hello Dolly"`, I do the change exactly in one single place.

I would like to achieve the same in C++.
Example:

```
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];

options[0].optionString = (char *)"-Djava.class.path=.";
```

This works, no more questions, but I don't like it because of the requirement to be able to change it in one place only if required.
So, I declare (even in the header file):

```
std::string classpath = "-Djava.class.path=.";
// or
const std::string classpath = "-Djava.class.path=.";
```

and I use it as:

```
options[0].optionString = (char *)classpath.c_str();
```

Now, using the `c_str()` function, this works also, but I'm back to plain old C!

I would really like to know if there is a mean to stay at a more modern C++ level?

Yes I know,

```
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
```

is declared as it is and I can't change it. But even in C++ it's a good idea to work with a reference rather than with a pointer in the given case, as in Java. Is there a solution? I was not able to find one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312860/correct-idiom-for-stdstring-constants - helpful?

Comment: If you're using an API that takes C strings, there's no way around a conversion *somewhere*. For a constant, though, I'd suggest `std::string_view` if possible. It doesn't allocate, but is about as useful as a `std::string`.

Comment: Unless you *really* need to allocate it dynamically (you probably don't) start by just using `JavaVMOption options;`. If that insists on using C-like code (e.g., pointers to char instead of strings) you probably want to create a wrapper for *it* that lets you use `std::string` where it makes sense, and supports creation of an actual `JavaVMOption` when needed.

Comment: The `char*` cast is downright scary. Certainly in the context of `options[0].optionString = `. Because it looks like that's not a string at all, despite the name.

Comment: OK, I guess std::string_view may be a good int. Being such a long time far from C++, I didn't know. I'll have a closer look.

Answer (score 2):

`"Hello"` is a const buffer of 6 `char` of value `H` `e` `l` `l` `o` `\0` respectively whose lifetime is the entire program.

```
std::string bob = "Hello";
```

copies that buffer into a `std::string` object.  `std::string` is a value semantics object; this is something that Java tends to lack, as all objects are implicitly passed by reference everywhere.

```
options[0].optionString = (char *)"-Djava.class.path=.";
```

this is extremely dangerous.  You cast that buffer to a non-`const` pointer to `char`, then assigned it to `optionString`.

I have no idea what `optionString` is, but if it is a variable of type `char*`, this is opening you up to undefined behavior.  Any editing of the buffer `"-Djava.class.path=."` is undefined behavior, and storing a non-`const` pointer to such a buffer is just begging for that to happen.

In short, the type of `optionString` is key to how dangerous that is.  Is it merely reckless, or actually really stupid?

```
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
```

this creates on the heap an array of `JavaVMOption` of size `1` then stores a pointer to the first element in `options`.

There are so many pointless things here.  And destroying that requires destroying it as an array?

```
JavaVMOption options;
```

this creates a `JavaVMOption` on the stack called `options`.  It is automatically destroyed at the end of scope.  This seems much more practical.  There is no point in using `new` unless you need `new`, and you rarely need `new` in C++.

I found some sample code:

```
#include <jni.h>       /* where everything is defined */
...
JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/usr/lib/java";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
 * pointer in env */
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
delete options;
/* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
jclass cls = env->FindClass("Main");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);
/* We are done. */
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
```

and that wasn't written by someone who programs in C++ for a living.

Here is my initial stab at it:

```
struct destroy_java_vm {
  void operator()(JavaVM* jvm)const{
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
  }
};
using up_java_vm = std::unique_ptr< JavaVM, destroy_java_vm >;

struct java_vm {
  up_java_vm vm;
  JNIEnv* env = 0;
};
struct java_vm_option {
  std::string string;
  std::shared_ptr<void> extra_info;
};
using java_vm_options = std::vector<java_vm_option>;

struct java_vm_init {
  unsigned version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
  java_vm_options options;
  bool ignore_unrecognized = false;
  java_vm init() {
    std::vector<JavaVMOption> java_options(options.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < options.size(); ++i) {
      java_options[i].optionString = &options.string[0];
      java_options[i].extraInfo = options.extra_info.get();
    }
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    args.version = version;
    args.options = java_options.data();
    args.nOptions = java_options.size();
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = ignore_unrecognized?TRUE:FALSE;
    java_vm retval;
    JavaVM* tmp = 0;
    auto res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&tmp, (void **)&retval.env, &args);
    if (res < 0) {
      return {}; // error message?  How?
    }
    retval.vm.reset( tmp );
    return retval;
  }
}
```

Use:

```
java_vm_init init;
init.options.push_back("-Djava.class.path=.");
auto vm = init.init();
if (!vm.env) { return /* error case */; }
/* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
jclass cls = vm.env->FindClass("Main");
jmethodID mid = vm.env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V");
vm.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);
/* We are done. */
```

By my use of `unique_ptr`, a `java_vm` object is a value type that is move-only.  When it is destroyed, the java vm is destroyed automatically (if you didn't move it out).

We have to move over to C-style code when talking directly to the API, because many cross-language APIs are written using C-style interfaces.  We wrap that C-style interface in a safer and easier to use C++ type.

Code not tested, probably contains typos.

Comment: @TobySpeight Fixed.  Also was missing a `)`.

Comment: The sample code you found is the point. The goal ist to access services of the OS from Java. The required interface must be written in c or c++ compiled and linked as a library which can be loaded by the java VM to access the OS services  through JNI. You say the sample code was not written by someone who programs c++ for living. Proabely the JNI interface neither, just plain old C. I just try to find a way in the jungle and I try to understand what I'm doing! Hence the reason of the question. And you got my goal, to wrap that c-style interface in a safer C++ type.

Comment: @Juerg The sample code I found uses `new`, but is written like a C program.  I have tried to sketch a way to do it cleanly in C++, hiding the details of the C-like interface behind some thin C++ types.

Comment: Thanks Yakk. I'll try it ASAP. I'm transforming the house actually, hence hundred tasks at the same time! :))

Answer (score 0):

I'm a java programmer and I found the same example when trying to use JNI to call Java from C++.  That said, I don't know if this is "correct", but it got the code to compile without errors by changing the original code:

```
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];   // JVM invocation options
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=."
```

To use a char array instead.

```
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
char classpath[] = "-Djava.class.path=.";
options[0].optionString = classpath;
```

My basic understanding is that a char* is the same as a char[].