# Any advantage of using the s suffix in C++

Tags: c++, stdstring, auto, c++17

My question is related to the use of the "s" suffix in C++?

Example of code using the "s" suffix:

```
auto hello = "Hello!"s; // a std::string
```

The same could be written as:

```
auto hello = std::string{"Hello!"};
```

I was able to find online that the "s" suffix should be used to minimizes mistakes and to clarify our intentions in the code.

Therefore, is the use of the "s" suffix only meant for the reader of the code? Or are there others advantages to its use?

Comment: i wonder if this addresses an old concern of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312860/correct-idiom-for-stdstring-constants

Comment: The example on this page may shows at least 1 advantage: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: Better to avoid using `auto` in such cases than use such weird workarounds

Comment: @Rpessoa - you would be better off without 'auto' in your sample. It is confusing readers of the question

Comment: @MichaelWalz: you miss a `const` Btw: `const char* hello = "Hello";`

Comment: @pm100 - I used the auto in purpose. If I had `std::string hello{"Hello"};` or `std::string hello = "hello";` why would I need to use the "s" suffix? I already included the std::string, so it would be clear that I wanted a string. Maybe I am missing some of the use of the "s" suffix. Just as a clarification, how would you re-write my code example?

Answer (score 36):

Null characters can be included in the raw string trivially;  example from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    std::string s1 = "abc\0\0def";
    std::string s2 = "abc\0\0def"s;
    std::cout << "s1: " << s1.size() << " \"" << s1 << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "s2: " << s2.size() << " \"" << s2 << "\"\n";
}
```

Possible output:

```
s1: 3 "abc"
s2: 8 "abc^@^@def"
```

Comment: ooo - good one.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 17):

> Therefore, is the use of the "s" suffix only meant for the reader of the code?

No, its not only for the reader of the code, but tells the compiler which exact type to create from the literal.

> Or are there others advantages to its use?

Sure: There is the advantage to write that code shorter but yet yielding the wanted type

```
auto hello = "Hello!"s;
```

As you noticed this creates a `std::string` and is the same as writing

```
auto hello = std::string{"Hello!"};
```

, whereas

```
auto hello = "Hello!";
```

would create a `const char*` pointer pointing to a `const char[7]` array.

Comment: the question is 'whats these difference between the 2 std::string initalizations?' - not 'what happens if i leave the s off?'

Comment: @pm100 Clearer now?

Comment: nope. Its obvious its less typing. But are there other advantages. For example is it more efficent at run time. std::string has/had no way of making constants - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312860/correct-idiom-for-stdstring-constants

Comment: @TheDude `auto hello = "Hello!";` would rather create a `const char *` than `const char[7]`;

Comment: ukmonkey points out a great advantage

Comment: @pm100 Yes, the `\0` characters inline in that literal are a neat thing.

Comment: Although this actually answers the question "Is there a disadvantage to using the s suffix?", it still makes a really good point. It's easy to forget the s and wind up with the wrong type.