# How to make a string variable that contains more than one letter?

Tags: c++, variables

Using char only you can make a single character variable. How would you make a variable with a word? After searching i found this way:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
char word[] = "computer";
std::cout<< "choose" << word << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Which gives what i need but it is not the proper way to do it i think?
So is this the correct way: to put empty brackets after the variable of char?

Comment: What source are you learning C++ from? (Also, `#include iostream` is a syntax error.)

Comment: `std::string word = "computer"s;` should work well.

Comment: There are various ways of declaring your variable. You can either use char array or a char pointer or a string data type. It  depends what you are looking for and how you are going to use your variable in  your code

Comment: `std::string` is managed and holds a shed load of useful utility. Typically constant char pointers to string literals and char arrays, should only be used in place of `std::string` when using a legacy interface, or (only really in extreme cases) for optimisation purposes.

Comment: If you just need to handle some predefined string constant then you can write `auto const & word{"computer"};`.

Comment: Thanks George and TheDude. I agree. Deleted the comment.

Comment: what is the "s" and what it does?

Comment: @J_p See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465116/any-advantage-of-using-the-s-suffix-in-c);

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is not a string but a character [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array) initialized [with](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) a string literal. Idiomatic way of working with strings in C++ is utilizing the standard [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) type and invoking one of its [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), for example the one accepting a `std::initializer` list:

```
std::string word{"computer"};
```

or the copy constructor:

```
std::string word("computer");
```

or using the strings [operator=](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) to assign the value of a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to your variable.

```
std::string word;
word = "computer";
```

Be sure to include the `<string>` header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string word{ "computer" }; // starting with C++11
    std::string word2("computer 2");
    std::string word3;
    word3 = "computer 3";
    std::cout << word << '\n';
}
```

Comment: cant make it work. can you explain?for example where did the name of the variable "word" went?

Comment: `std::string` is not built-in, but it is standard, which is close enough.

Comment: it says `[Error] in C++98 'word' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'`

Comment: The C++98 standard does not support the initializer lists. Use parentheses instead of braces. The right most column in the above links (the text in green) indicates the standard and availability.

Comment: @J_p Why are you using a standard 20 years out of date?

Comment: i downloaded devc++ and this is what it had. Also i just started with the c++.Why it had the 98 release???

Comment: @J_p devc is capable of working with newer toolchains, simply get the lates version of GCC and install that one.

Comment: i picked 11 iso. i typed also your answer with the "s" and it says `[Error] 'word' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @J_p Did you miss `#include <string>`?