# Correct usage of string_view and s suffix

Tags: c++17, stdstring, string-view

I would like to evaluate the following code to understand the benefits of using `string_view` and s suffix.

```
std::string word{"apple"};
foo(word);
foo("banana");
foo("banana"s);
bar(word);
bar("banana");
bar("banana"s);
```

Here, `foo` and `bar` function prototype is as follows.

```
foo(const std::string& w);
bar(std::string_view w);
```

Comparing `foo(word)` and `bar(word)`.

- `foo(word)`: call-by-reference, no additional object is created.
- `bar(word)`: temporary `std::string_view` object is created but does not require additional allocation or copying.

Comparing `foo("")` and `bar("")`.

- `foo("banana")`: a temporary `std::string` object is created. It requires dynamic allocation and copying.
- `foo("banana"s)`: same as previous except the temporary `std::string` object is created more efficiently. ([Any advantage of using the s suffix in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465116/any-advantage-of-using-the-s-suffix-in-c/48465238))
- `bar("banana")`: a temporary `std::string_view` object is created but does not require additional allocation or copying.
- `bar("banana"s)`: a temporary `std::string` object and a temporary `std::string_view` object are created.

My conclusion is as follows: use `std::string_view` instead of `const std::string&` and do not use s suffix when passing a string literal. Is there anything wrong with this analysis or anything I missed?

Comment: _"`foo("banana")`: a temporary `string` object is created."_ no, a temporary string literal is created. that's a zero-terminated const char array. And `string_view` is _always_ non-owning: it's just a pointer and a length. It always needs something to reference to. Please make discrepancy between "string" and `std::string` to clarify the question.

Comment: I think in ```foo("banana")``` case, a c-string literal is created which is used to create a temporary ```std::string``` which is passed as a reference. In this case, there is no advantage in using call-by-reference. Using call-by-value with copy-elision would behave near identically except for the location of temporary ```std::string''' object.

Comment: No, no temporary `std::string` is created. A `std::string_view` can directly point to a C string or string literal (and many other types strings): it just contains the pointer to the start of the string and the length. It's a view. If `std::string_view` would only be bound to `std::string`, it wouldn't add much value... we could have better used `std::string const&`.