# C++ unordered_map<string, ...> lookup without constructing string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, unordered-map

I have C++ code that investigates a BIG string and matches lots of substrings.  As much as possible, I avoid constructing std::strings, by encoding substrings like this:

```
char* buffer, size_t bufferSize
```

At some point, however, I'd like to look up a substring in one of these:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Info> stringToInfo = {...
```

So, to do that, I go:

```
stringToInfo.find(std::string(buffer, bufferSize))
```

That constructs a std::string for the sole purpose of the lookup.

I feel like there's an optimization I could do here, by... changing the key-type of the unordered_map to some kind of temporary string imposter,   a class like this...

```
class SubString
{
    char* buffer;
    size_t bufferSize;

    // ...
};
```

... that does the same logic as std::string to hash and compare, but then doesn't deallocate its buffer when it's destroyed.

So, my question is: is there a way to get the standard classes to do this, or do I write this class myself?

Comment: That sounds a lot like `string_view`, but it is a C++17 feature AFAIK. [Possibly related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525777/use-of-string-view-for-map-lookup)

Comment: For me it is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you describe algorithm/problem you are writing/solving?

Comment: Just implement it. What's the problem?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view

Comment: If you use `std::string` as the map's key type, you can manually iterate the map instead of using `find()`, comparing each key using `std::string::compare()`, which can take `char*`+length for the input string being compared to

Comment: @Norrius but [`experimental::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view) is usable pre-C++17.

Comment: i asked this exact thing before, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312860/correct-idiom-for-stdstring-constants

Answer (score 8):

What you're wanting to do is called *heterogeneous lookup*.  Since C++14 it's been supported for [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) and [`std::set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) (note versions (3) and (4) of the functions, which are templated on the lookup value type).  It's more complicated for unordered containers because they need to be told of or find hash functions for all key types that will produce the same hash value for the same text.  There's a proposal under consideration for a future Standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r0.html

Meanwhile, you could use another library that already supports heterogenous lookup, e.g. [`boost::unordered_map::find`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html).

If you want to stick to `std::unordered_map`, you could avoid creating so many string temporaries by storing a `std::string` member alongside your `unordered_map` that you can reassign values to, then pass that `string` to `find`.  You could encapsulate this in a custom container class.

Another route is to write a custom class to use as your unordered container key:

```
struct CharPtrOrString
{
    const char* p_;
    std::string s_;

    explicit CharPtrOrString(const char* p) : p_{p} { }
    CharPtrOrString(std::string s) : p_{nullptr}, s_{std::move(s)} { }

    bool operator==(const CharPtrOrString& x) const
    {
        return p_ ? x.p_ ? std::strcmp(p_, x.p_) == 0
                         : p_ == x.s_
                  : x.p_ ? s_ == x.p_
                         : s_ == x.s_;
    }

    struct Hash
    {
        size_t operator()(const CharPtrOrString& x) const
        {
            std::string_view sv{x.p_ ? x.p_ : x.s_.c_str()};
            return std::hash<std::string_view>()(sv);
        } 
    };
};
```

You can then construct `CharPtrOrString` from `std::string`s for use in the unordered container keys, but construct one cheaply from your `const char*` each time you call `find`.  Note that `operator==` above has to work out which you did (convention used is that if the pointer's `nullptr` then the `std::string` member's in use) so it compares the in-use members.  The hash function has to make sure a `std::string` with a particular textual value will produce the same hash as a `const char*` (which it *doesn't* by default with GCC 7.3 and/or Clang 6 - I work with both and remember one had an issue but not which).

Answer (score 4):

In C++20, you can now do this:

```cpp
// struct is from "https://www.cppstories.com/2021/heterogeneous-access-cpp20/"
struct string_hash {
    using is_transparent = void;
    [[nodiscard]] size_t operator()(const char *txt) const {
        return std::hash<std::string_view>{}(txt);
    }
    [[nodiscard]] size_t operator()(std::string_view txt) const {
        return std::hash<std::string_view>{}(txt);
    }
    [[nodiscard]] size_t operator()(const std::string &txt) const {
        return std::hash<std::string>{}(txt);
    }
};


// Declaration of map
std::unordered_map<std::string, Info, string_hash, std::equal_to<>> map;

std::string_view key = "foo";
if (map.find(key))
{
    // do something here
}
```

Just note that you will still need `std::string` when using `[]`. There may be a way around that, but I'm not too sure