# Looking up c-string key in `std::string`-keyed hash

Tags: c++, c++17

I have `std::unordered_map<std::string, MyType>`.

I get a `char const* key`, which I need to look up.
Is there anyway to do it without constructing `std::string(key)` to avoid memory copy?

As I understand, C++20 allows it:

**`std::unordered_map<Key,T,Hash,KeyEqual,Allocator>::find`** :

```
      template<class K> iterator find( const K& x );
```

So I can use `std::string_view` as `K`. Any way to do it in C++17?

Comment: Of course you can.  Either use the std::string_view once argument constructor, or let the compiler do it automatically for you, by calling `std:::unordered_map<>::find(your_char_ptr); Recent std libraries wlilll correctly call the string_view constructor from there.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy _"Of course"_ [Are you sure?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff95fab76bf3d65e)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ unordered\_map<string, ...> lookup without constructing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709548/c-unordered-mapstring-lookup-without-constructing-string)

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Wouldn't `mymap.find(your_cchar_ptr)` be equivalent to `mymap.find( std::string(your_cchar_ptr) )`?

Comment: I honestly doubt that you can, but, if I might ask, why are you using `std::string`s in the first place here?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  Thank you.  I've checked it out, and youu're right.  c++ std::unordered_map::find() does not have an overload that taes a string_view.  This makes this question moot.  Please dieregard my previous comment.  I was wrong.  I will not remove it so the rest of the conversation makes sense.    Code at https://godbolt.org/z/1s4zxv

Comment: @xxh I am not understanding your question. If my keys are strings, what other type could I use for them?

Comment: @user2052436 `std::string_view`s do not require any extra memory allocations, they're what I've used for `std::map`s before. But I understand if changing the actual map itself isn't allowed, or a viable option.